# XQuartz xterm UTF-8 resource name

Tags: x11, unicode, x-resources

I was using UTF-8 resources names like these ones:

```
wengé*Background:      #321
wengé*Foreground:      #ffb
```

and this was working with XQuartz 2.8.1 through this direct
call like from within the XQuartx menu:

```
xterm -name wengé
```

Since I upgraded it to XQuartz 2.8.5 this doesn't work anymore:
the default color resources are used, but strangely, the `xterm`
window title get its correct UTF-8 name.
During this upgrade the system shell was switched from `/bin/bash` to `/bin/zsh`.

If I start from an existing `xterm` window:

```
xterm -name wengé
```

it works correctly.

All the Xresources definitions without an UTF-8 name work correctly
from within the XQuartz menu, for example with `olive`:

```
$ xrdb -q | egrep 'olive|wengé'
olive*Background:       #335511
olive*Foreground:       #99ff99
wengé*Background:       #321
wengé*Foreground:       #ffb
```

What may cause this strange change in behaviour?
How may I further debug it?

Comment: FWIW, here on Debian, I find that I need `xterm -name 'weng\U000000e9'` for the settings loaded with `xrdb -merge <<< 'wengé*Background: #f00'` to be honoured. `xrdb -q` shows that `é` represented as `\U000000e9`.